# Connection String not found WPF Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, wpf, mvvm, connectionstring

Estou em um projeto WPF usando algumas práticas de MVVM, estou usando Entity Framework database first e a connection string já está no app.config, já segui todos os procedimentos que li em diversas questões porém na view aparece essa mensagem no DataContext

[image: Erro na View]

### Abaixo a connectionstring que já está no app.config

```
 <add name="TimerEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Timer.csdl|res://*/Timer.ssdl|res://*/Timer.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=C:\Users\Angelica\Documents\DB\Timer.sdf;Max Database Size=4091&quot;"
 providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

---

O Contexto do banco de dados

```
using System;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;

public partial class TimerEntities : DbContext
{
    public TimerEntities()
        : base("name=TimerEntities")
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
    }

    public virtual DbSet<CAIXA> CAIXAS { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<CLIENTE> CLIENTES { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<ORDEM> ORDEM { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<PACOTE> PACOTES { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<TEMPO> TEMPOS { get; set; }
}
```

---

Procedimentos que já fiz e não funcionaram:

1. Remover o "name" do Contexto;
2. Colocar a *connection string* em outro arquivo `config` e fazer o link no `app.config`;
3. Comentar `throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();`;

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
  </configSections>
    <connectionStrings>
      <add name="TimerEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Timer.csdl|res://*/Timer.ssdl|res://*/Timer.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=C:\Users\Angelica\Documents\DB\Timer.sdf;Max Database Size=4091&quot;"
     providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6" />
  </startup>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlCeConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServerCompact.SqlCeProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServerCompact" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" />
      <add name="Microsoft SQL Server Compact Data Provider 4.0" invariant="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" description=".NET Framework Data Provider for Microsoft SQL Server Compact" type="System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeProviderFactory, System.Data.SqlServerCe, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Preciso do conteúdo do `App1.config` completo. Pode por favor atualizar sua pergunta?

Comment: Bom dia, a configuração dentro do seu arquivo app.config está certa ? Você chegou a fazer um teste para verificar se a conexão com o Banco está sendo feita ?

Comment: Já editei! Obrigada pela ajuda!

Comment: Por que o arquivo chama `App1.config`? Devia se chamar apenas `App.config`. Ao fazer o *Build* do seu projeto, ele passa a chamar `SeuProjeto.config`.

Comment: Bom dia Diego, então quando eu coloco o Command em um button meu design time aparece o erro de Você está usando code first em um banco de dados que foi gerado em databasefirst, algo assim! Aí eu tive que remover o Command do button! Para explicar melhor esse programa é um contador de tempo para equipamentos de um quiosque de um shopping! Portanto só populei alguns dados no banco de dados! Mas por exemplo no meu viewModel eu tenho uma propriedade chamad tbDataAtual que simplesmente retorna o Datetime.Now e com esse erro nem isso está retornando! Obrigada.

Comment: É porque por achar que era algum problema com o app.config original do projeto eu excluí ele e coloquei outro para teste! Mas não funcionou mesmo assim!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isto me parece má configuração de projeto. O arquivo de configuração está ok, mas aparentemente não está sendo devidamente reconhecido.

Há algumas coisas que você pode fazer para contornar o problema rapidamente:

#### 1. Não usando `name=TimerEntities` no construtor do contexto

Ficaria assim:

```
public TimerEntities()
    : base("TimerEntities")
{
}
```

#### 2. Passando a *connection string* diretamente para o construtor base

Ficaria assim:

```
public TimerEntities()
    : base("metadata=res://*/Timer.csdl|res://*/Timer.ssdl|res://*/Timer.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=C:\Users\Angelica\Documents\DB\Timer.sdf;Max Database Size=4091&quot;")
{
}
```

Este último não é exatamente recomendado. Só use em caso de urgência.

Comment: Sim eu já havia utilizado a primeira opção e recebo a seguinte informação na View

Comment: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error  The context is being used in Code First mode with code that was generated from an EDMX file for either Database First or Model First development.  This will not work correctly. To fix this problem do not remove the line of code that throws this exception. If you wish to use Database First or Model First, then make sure that the Entity Framework connection string is included in the app.config or web.config of the start-up project.

Comment: CONTINUANDO.... then make sure that it is an EntityConnection and not some other type of DbConnection, and that you pass it to one of the base DbContext constructors that take a DbConnection. To learn more about Code First, Database First, and Model First see the Entity Framework documentation

Comment: Sim, isso acontece porque você usou `throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();` no `OnModelCreate`. Pode removê-lo agora.

Comment: E eu criei o modelo em EF designer from database!

Comment: Eu havia tentado tirar também e surge mais um erro! Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error  A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified) StartTimer C:\Users\Angelica\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\StartTimer\StartTimer\Views\CaixaWindow.xaml 11

Comment: Eu estou usando o SqlCompact, mas já tentei também usar o SQLite e é o mesmo erro, depois de todos essas passos!

Comment: Este segundo erro quer dizer que a aplicação não consegue se conectar ao SQL Server CE. No seu lugar, [eu usaria o SQL Server LocalDb](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/sqlserver2014express.aspx), que é o mesmo princípio e o suporte é melhor.

Comment: Bom acho que já achei o problema! Esses dias quando fui fazer o update 3 do VS deu um b.ozinho e travou a instalação...então tive que reparar o pc para voltar... e não tinha me notado que o SQL SERVER DATA TOOLS não estava instalado! Portanto acho que é isso o erro! Estou instalando agora e vamos ver se dá certo! Obrigada pela dica e por disponibilizar seu tempo para me ajudar, eu vou pesquisar sobre o LocalDb.